# Issue in Multilevel ExpandableListview in android

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview, pull-to-refresh

Scroll Issue in Multilevel ExpandableListview in android

I have browsed for implementing multilevel ExpandableListView and i came to know with very important

**blogs :**
[Link1](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html)
[Link2](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html)

**Stackoverflow** Link:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765638/how-to-display-more-than-3-level-of-expandable-list-view?rq=1)

Implemented multilevel ExpandableListview with [Blog](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html) but faced problem that all child not visible and can't scroll at 3rd level. So i searched for scrolling issues and found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869046/multilevel-expandablelistview-not-highlighting-properly) that which blog i am following gave static height and width of ExpandableListview in **onMessured**.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
  {
   widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(960, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
   heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }
```

**replaced with**

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

So my scrolling issue gone but because of maximum height .

```
heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
```

given to elv getChildView of 2nd Elv called only once and all child loading at first time. This will causing memory issue for large set of data and i can't applied pull to refresh.

how to resolve this issue and any batter idea to implement multilevel ELV?